# Pygments and ImageFormatter: set output to 80 columns

Tags: python, pygments

The `ImageFormatter` always creates a PNG output which width depends on the line length.

For example, this PNG is 192 pixels wide:

[image: short]

and this is 384:

[image: long]

Is there a setting in `Pygments` to emulate a 80 column output, so all images will have the same width?

This is the code I used to produce the examples:

```
#!/usr/bin/python3

from pygments import highlight
from pygments import lexers
from pygments.formatters.img import ImageFormatter
from pygments.styles import get_style_by_name, get_all_styles

lexer = lexers.get_lexer_by_name('C')

source_short = 'printf("%d\\n", i);'
source_long = 'printf("variable i is equal to %d.\\n", i);'

formatter = ImageFormatter(full = True, style = get_style_by_name('vim'))
open('short.png', 'wb').write(highlight(source_short, lexer, formatter))
formatter = ImageFormatter(full = True, style = get_style_by_name('vim'))
open('long.png', 'wb').write(highlight(source_long, lexer, formatter))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that the easiest way to pad to 80 columns is to actually pad the first line of the file with extra blank spaces. This is my routine to read it:

```py
def readCode(filename,columns):
    with open(filename,'r') as f:
        lines = f.read().split('\n')
        maxw = max( [ len(line) for line in lines ] )
        if maxw<columns:
            lines[0] = lines[0] + ' '*(columns-maxw)
        return '\n'.join(lines)
```

and then use it

```py
code = readCode(filename, 80)
lexer = get_lexer_for_filename(filename)
highlight(code, lexer,  
              ImageFormatter(style=style),  
              outfile=outfilename)
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if it's the best way, but worked for me.

This is `MyFormatter`, from `ImageFormatter`, in which the number of characters in line is always 80. The method `format` was minimally altered.

```
from pygments.formatter import Formatter
from pygments.util import get_bool_opt, get_int_opt, get_list_opt, \
    get_choice_opt, xrange
from PIL import Image, ImageDraw, ImageFont
import subprocess

class MyFormatter(ImageFormatter):
    def __init__(self, **options):
        super().__init__(**options)

    def format(self, tokensource, outfile):
        self._create_drawables(tokensource)
        self._draw_line_numbers()
        im = Image.new(
            'RGB',
            self._get_image_size(80, self.maxlineno), # always 80
            self.background_color
        )
        self._paint_line_number_bg(im)
        draw = ImageDraw.Draw(im)
        # Highlight
        if self.hl_lines:
            x = self.image_pad + self.line_number_width - self.line_number_pad + 1
            recth = self._get_line_height()
            rectw = im.size[0] - x
            for linenumber in self.hl_lines:
            y = self._get_line_y(linenumber - 1)
            draw.rectangle([(x, y), (x + rectw, y + recth)],
                       fill=self.hl_color)
        for pos, value, font, kw in self.drawables:
            draw.text(pos, value, font=font, **kw)
        im.save(outfile, self.image_format.upper())
```